# If Statement and toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a bit of noob when it comes to Javascript. Basically I have a simple ul with 5 li's attached

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgba(221,221,221,.5);
}


li a:hover {
    background-color:rgba(221,221,221,.5);
}
.active {
    background-color: rgba(22,47,127,.25);
}

<ul class="topnav" id="ulclass">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick= "addNavLayer(Points);">Display Points</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addNavLayer(States);">Display States</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addNavLayer(Counties);">Display Counties</a></li></li>

  </ul>

$("ul a").click(function(){
//this works fine at just toggling the boxes
    $(this).toggleClass("active");


});
```

Here's the tricky part...an if statements that says

If li item 2 is active (state layer), then de-activate li item 3 (county layer)

Else li 3 is active (county layer), then de-activate li item 2 (state layer)

I know it's possible in jQuery I'm just having trouble referencing the individual items in the list and then toggling the active state.

Comment: you should share all relevant code. That includes `addNavLayer` and whatever `Points`, `States`, and `Countries` are.

Comment: What you mean by deactivating li 2 ?
$(this).hasClass('className') and then toggle ... (add/removeClass)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
$("ul a").click(function(){
    //first remove all instances of the class
    $("ul a").removeClass("active");
    //then set the active
    $(this).addClass("active");    
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xzsa7py3/

if you want the first anchor to toggle independently you can add a class to the others and use something like this

```
$("ul a").click(function(){
    //remove class from anchors that have class 'should-toggle'
    $("ul a.should-toggle").removeClass("active");
    //add class to selected
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: upon closer inspection I see you want to keep the first seperate from the toggle options, try this https://jsfiddle.net/xzsa7py3/1/

Comment: yep that's what i'm doing. trying to separate that first one. really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `jQuery`'s `.index()`. This can get you the index of whatever `li` element there is. Keep in mind this is `0` based.

You can just set `var elementIndex = $('li').index($(this).parent());`

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function(){
  
  console.log(
    $('li').index($(this).parent())
  );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a>List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a>List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Documentation

**`.index()`** - https://api.jquery.com/index/